# Is it possible to simplify this regular expression any further?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I'm working on some homework for my compiler class and I have the following problem:

Write a regular expression for all strings of *a*'s and *b*'s that contain an odd number of *a*'s or an odd number of *b*'s (or both).

After a lot of whiteboard work I came up with the following solution:

```
(aa|bb)* (ab|ba|a|b) ((aa|bb)* (ab|ba) (aa|bb)* (ab|ba) (aa|bb)*)*
```

However, Is this is the most simplified I can get it?  I've considered constructing the DFA trying to minimize the number of states there to see if it would help me simplify but I figured I would ask the regex gurus on SO first.

Comment: What advanced features of regex are you allowed to use?

Comment: he is using regular expressions in Computer Science, not PCRE or posix regex's ;) They are different.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, I assume we are only allowed to use the regex which has been introduced so far in the book which isn't much.  (*, +, ?, |, [], ^).  Pretty plain.

Comment: Brings back memories from when I graded such homework as a TA.  Some of the most interesting stuff I've graded, by far.  :)

Comment: +1 for asking "why/how?" when the answer was posted.  :)

Comment: Thank you everyone!  From the combined insight of Greg D, Walt W, and sepp2k we were able to come up with a valid answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take Greg D's recommendation of starting with a(aa)*, and going from there.  Sepp2k almost has it right, but the real consideration is that you don't care about the other letter.  What I mean is, when you are looking at the "odd number of a's" constraint, you don't care at all about what b's are in your string.  Thus, stick b*'s anywhere you can :)

Sepp2k's answer is almost right, but this one is correct:

```
b* a b* (a b* a b* )* | a* b a* (b a* b a* )*
```

To elaborate, this regex figures out all strings with an odd number of a's (first section), and OR's those strings with any strings containing an odd number of b's.

Comment: @Walt W, I'm running this one through its paces but I think you are correct.

Comment: please tell me the regular expression for any string that contain even number of a's and even number of b's ?

Comment: Do you mean an even number of a's OR an even number of b's?  I suppose you could do an AND with zero-length lookaheads...  That's not standard regex stuff though.  If you want to change this equation from odd to even, just drop the first two terms of each segment (b*a from the left side and a*b from the right side)

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
b* a b* (a b* a b*)* |  a* b a* (b a* b a*)*
```

Comment: I was writing something similar :) To elaborate, this regex figures out all strings with an odd number of a's (first section), and OR's those strings with any strings containing an odd number of b's.  There's a slight error here though, as first term needs b* at the end, and second option needs a* at the end.  Otherwise, abbba will not be accepted.

Comment: @sepp2k, this is working in all my test cases.  Can you describe your thought process when you were making that?  It is far simpler than the path I was going down.

Comment: Nobody said it can't be ambiguous.  Walt is correct, it isn't finished, but all the important bits are there.  :)

Comment: @Walt W: You're absolutely right. Fixed. @Simucal: Walt explained it pretty well.

Comment: @sepp2k, yea, we submitted out comments at the same time.

Comment: @sepp2k: Err, I was a little wrong, you need the b* / a* at the end to be inside the parenthesis, or else you can't have b's between two groups of two a's (like aaabbaa).  I posted an answer with that fix..

Comment: I think this might fail on: ABBBABB.

Comment: Simulcal: Refer to my last comment / answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that I don't believe your regex as written is correct.  Consider the string:

```
aba
```

We have a couple choices for matches, but the fact that it's odd-length means we must match a lone a at the front, so:

```
(a)(ba)
```

But, sadly, it's impossible for your second main grouping there to match (ba).

When dealing with a constraint like this, I found it easier to start from the core constraint and go from there.  In this case, your constraint is "odd," so start with

```
a(aa)*
```

to force an odd number of `a`'s and go from there.  :)

Comment: @Greg D, that is true.  Let me think on it for a second.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to approach the problem differently.

You are trying to match anything that doesn't have even numbers of both `a` and `b`.

It would probably be easier to start with something that matches *even* numbers of `a` and `b`. All you have to do at that point would be to add something on the end that matches the smallest string that you actually want to match.